# Merge data from multiple columns into one

Tags: sql

I have three columns X, Y & Z. I want to do a select statement that returns only one column.
For example for the following rows:

```
X Y Z
1 0 0 
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

I want to return one column A:

```
A
X 
Y
Z
```

So, wherever there is one, the column should return a string corresponding to the column name where it is one..

I don't have rights to create a new column in the database and then update it using where condition. So I was wondering if it could be done inside a SELECT statement

Comment: I absolutely don't understand what you want...

Comment: Your google search string is `sql case in select`.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: What if there are two columns with the value `1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without dealing with multiple `1` values in one row:

```
select case
         when x = 1 then 'X' 
         when y = 1 then 'Y'
         when z = 1 then 'Z'
       end as A
from the_table;
```

---

If you are using Postgres and have a primary key column on that table, you can use JSON functions to make this dynamic and not hardcode the column names in the query.

Test data setup:

```
create table the_table (id integer, x int, y int, z int);
insert into the_table 
  (id,x,y,z)
values
  (1, 1, 0, 0), 
  (2, 0, 1, 0),
  (3, 0, 0, 1),
  (4, 0, 1, 1),
  (5, 0, 0, 0);
```

Then using this query:

```
select t.id, string_agg(k.col,'' order by k.col) as non_zero_columns
from the_table t, 
     jsonb_each(to_jsonb(t) - 'id') as k (col, val)
where k.val = '1'
group by id
order by id;
```

Will return this result:

```
id | non_zero_columns
---+-----------------
 1 | x               
 2 | y               
 3 | z               
 4 | yz
```

Note that the row with ID=5 is not returned because all columns are zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple columns with 1s in one row:

```
select ((case when x = 1 then 'X' else '' end) ||
        (case when y = 1 then 'Y' else '' end) ||
        (case when z = 1 then 'Z' else '' end)
       ) as A
from the_table;
```

Note that `||` is the ANSI standard operator for string concatenation.  Some databases use other methods for concatenating strings.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Very true.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ms sq-server, you can use `UNPIVOT`

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (X INT, Y INT, Z INT)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
(1 ,0, 0 ),
(0 ,1, 0 ),
(0 ,0, 1 )

SELECT DISTINCT A FROM 
    (select * from @MyTable UNPIVOT( V FOR A IN ([X], [Y], [Z])) UNPVT) UP
WHERE V = 1
```

Result:

```
A
---------
X
Y
Z
```

Comment: You should mention for which database product your solution works as it contains a lot of non-standard syntax.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html) with [`find_in_set(str, strlist)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function (MySql):

```
-- the schema
create table `docs` (
  `X` int not null,
  `Y` int not null,
  `Z` int not null
);
insert into `docs` (`X`, `Y`, `Z`) values
  (1, 0, 0),
  (0, 1, 0),
  (0, 0, 1);

-- the query
select column_name as A, concat(x, y, z)
from docs
join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
on (ordinal_position = find_in_set('1', concat(x, ',', y, ',', z)))
where table_name like 'docs';
```

Here, the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/232e1/1)

Comment: It doesn't.  The OP doesn't want the schema, the OP wants results that are dependent on the data.  The row `0,0,1` should give, `z`, the row `1,0,0` should give `x`, the row `1,0,1` should ***presumably*** be impossible.  And this should, from reading the OP, apply to more rows than just those in the example.  *(I didn't down-vote, but I do maintain that this appears to be a misunderstanding of the requirement.)*

Comment: @MatBailie, it's right, I have read too quickly. I have modified my answer to give a result depending of the X, Y, and Z values.